# How to detect if a check box has been clicked and if it's selected using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have checkbox which once it's property of clicked is true, I would like to check another checkbox automatically.

I managed to partially get it working by changing the other value of the checkbox to true whenever the other is clicked. But this isn't what I want. I'd like to be able to check when the 'TwoFChk' checkbox is clicked and also if the property of checked is true at the same time. How do I do this?

JQuery:

```
if ($('#TwoFChk').change(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked', true)) {
            alert("It's checked");
            $('#ConfirmEmailChk').prop('checked', true);
        }
        }));
```

My question is different, here's why:

I'm not just trying to check if a checkbox is checked. I can do that already.
I need to detect when the value of checked changes, and if the value of checked is then true. I need to change the checked value of another checkbox is true. Again, I am not just trying to check if a checkbox is checked. I need to have an on click of the checkbox and if the checkbox checked value is true, then I need to check another checkbox.

Comment: You could `if(this.checked)`

Comment: `if ($('#TwoFChk').change(function () {...}));` What are you trying to check here???  It would be always truthly. Anyway, your question is missing relevant code and context, you have to provide minimalistic sample replicating issue

Comment: @A.Wolff Im trying to detect whenever the value of the checkbox has changed. And if that is the case, I need to check if its true and then change another checkboxes value. And not really, all I need to do is provide the JQuery code so people understand what im trying to convey

Comment: @AndrewKilburn And what if you remove the wrapping `if`, is the change event fired? Even it should be with the `if` but doesn't make sense. Anyway, again: `you have to provide minimalistic sample replicating issue`

Comment: So I would need to post this to JSFiddle? Not really as it's not a particularly difficult question

Comment: @AndrewKilburn I miised that you are setting it `if ($(this).prop('checked', true))`, not checking it `if(this.checked)`, `$(this).prop('checked', true)` is always truthly value

Comment: @A.Wolff Okay, thank you for your reply. I understand now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

use "$(this).prop("checked") == true"

```
  $('#TwoFChk').change(function () {
                if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                alert("It's checked");
                $('#ConfirmEmailChk').prop('checked', true);
            }
            });
```

Comment: @Deena No, my apologies. I was wrong. I believed that this line: 'if($(this).prop("checked") == true){'. Was the same: 'if ($(this).prop('checked', true)) {'

Comment: @AndrewKilburn `$(this).prop('checked', true)` would set it, just use `if(this.checked)`

Comment: @A.Wolff Ah, okay. I thought this would check if its true. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if a checkbox is checked with jQuery you can do so by using

```
$('#TwoFChk').is(':checked');
```